# Change jLabel image to image corresponding with Array Path?

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel

I'm working on a school project in which we have to make a card game using Java. I've been working on this for a bit (using GUI I've got my selection screen up and whatnot), and am currently writing code to flip cards over when you press a button (think the card game WAR). The player's cards are stored in a two dimensional array (cardDeck[playernum][cardnum]). The cardDeck is created from a custom Card class that I created, and I'm able to return the values of the card number and suit. I made some folders in the project directory corresponding to each suit, within each there are 13 image files, labeled 1.png to 13.png respectively. I want to be able to call an image based on what the user's top card is (for example, the return values are 9 and hearts, so I want to find the 9 of hearts in my image directory). I've tried using the following code for player 1's turn:

```
switch (playerTurn){
            case 1:
                Card value = playerDecks[0][0];
                int cardVal = value.returnUltimate();
                String cardSu = value.returnCardSuite();
                ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../../card game icons/" + cardSu + "/" + cardVal + ".png"));
                jLabel3.setIcon(newIcon);
                jLabel3.revalidate();

        }
```

However when I compile this with the rest of my code, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at cards.wargame.jButton1ActionPerformed(wargame.java:151)
at cards.wargame.access$000(wargame.java:14)
at cards.wargame$1.actionPerformed(wargame.java:66)
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Rather then use a relative pass, use an absolute pack from the top of your package ie `/resources/images/etc`.  Also remember, using `getResource` denotes that the images are within the classpath/embedded in the Jar

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried setting to "/home/ethan/netbeansprojects/cards/card game icons/......" but then got a different error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Your images need to be placed in your `src` directory (under some folder structure), then you can reference them via that folder structure using `getResource`